# Pandas: divide each row by another row depending on the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains the minute ticks of various securities from 930am-4pm every day. It looks like:

```
                  Date  TUA COMDTY  FVA COMDTY  TYA COMDTY  USA COMDTY  \
0  2014-03-14 09:30:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
1  2014-03-14 09:31:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
2  2014-03-14 09:32:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
3  2014-03-14 09:33:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
4  2014-03-14 09:34:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
5  2014-03-14 09:35:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
6  2014-03-14 09:36:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
7  2014-03-14 09:37:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
8  2014-03-14 09:38:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
9  2014-03-14 09:39:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
10 2014-03-14 09:40:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
11 2014-03-14 09:41:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
12 2014-03-14 09:42:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
13 2014-03-14 09:43:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
14 2014-03-14 09:44:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
15 2014-03-14 09:45:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
16 2014-03-14 09:46:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
17 2014-03-14 09:47:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
18 2014-03-14 09:48:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
19 2014-03-14 09:49:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
20 2014-03-14 09:50:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
21 2014-03-14 09:51:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
22 2014-03-14 09:52:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
23 2014-03-14 09:53:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
24 2014-03-14 09:54:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
25 2014-03-14 09:55:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
26 2014-03-14 09:56:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
27 2014-03-14 09:57:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
28 2014-03-14 09:58:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
29 2014-03-14 09:59:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
30 2014-03-14 10:00:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
31 2014-03-14 10:01:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
32 2014-03-14 10:02:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
33 2014-03-14 10:03:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
34 2014-03-14 10:04:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
35 2014-03-14 10:05:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
36 2014-03-14 10:06:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
37 2014-03-14 10:07:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
38 2014-03-14 10:08:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
39 2014-03-14 10:09:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
40 2014-03-14 10:10:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
41 2014-03-14 10:11:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
42 2014-03-14 10:12:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
43 2014-03-14 10:13:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
44 2014-03-14 10:14:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
45 2014-03-14 10:15:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
46 2014-03-14 10:16:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
47 2014-03-14 10:17:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
48 2014-03-14 10:18:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
49 2014-03-14 10:19:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
50 2014-03-14 10:20:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
51 2014-03-14 10:21:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
52 2014-03-14 10:22:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
53 2014-03-14 10:23:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
54 2014-03-14 10:24:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
55 2014-03-14 10:25:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
56 2014-03-14 10:26:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
57 2014-03-14 10:27:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
58 2014-03-14 10:28:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
59 2014-03-14 10:29:00  109.898438  119.523438  123.796875   131.34375   
                   ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
```

I'm trying to get a dataframe that reflects the price change from the previous day. Implemented as a loop, for each row, I would get the prices at 4pm from the previous day to divide the prices in the current row. 
Right now I'm doing resampling at 4pm every day, match index with the original matrix with forward filling. The new dataframe has the same dimension as the original, and contains the prices I need to divide with on each row. I then divide the two matrices. 
Is there an easier way to do this, using apply() for example? The function to be applied uses something like a vlookup in excel. The problem is I need the index (date) for each row, which is not available in apply(). 
Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Please supply some mockup data and expected output.

Comment: If distance between compared rows is constant (for example 15 rows) then you could create new "shifted" column using `shift(-15)` and then you have both values in one row.

Comment: Could you do us one last favor and `reset_index()` and paste again? That way, `pd.DataFrame(pd.read_clipboard())` will work correctly. With the indentation of `Date` (being the index) it does not.

Comment: Thank you furas. The distance is not constant. At 930, i want shift(-1), 931:shift(-2) etc. so that i'm always comparing with the row at 1600 on the previous day.

Comment: @FooBar There would be too many rows if I paste till 4pm. If you are trying to do it yourself, maybe compare all rows at 9:30+ with 9:30, 9:4x with the row at 9:40. Thank you.

Comment: so there's no way to do this.  I brought this up on the pandas list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are just doing return since close.

I have a hack for this purpose.  I resample the array to daily data and join it to my original frame.  Then I fill the closing price forward.
 How about something like this?

```
df_daily = df[df["Date"].hour == 16].copy().shift(1)
df = df.join(df_daily, rsuffix="closing_").fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I did. I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this. If not, I will accept this answer. Also, after you join, to divide the first half columns with the second half of columns, you need to break the dataframe into half and rename the columns again. All of these seem a little unwieldy.

Comment: it really is unwieldy.  I am going to open up an issue on pandas for it.